# Qt Parallel Port Interfacing

Tags: qt, parallel-port, qprinter, lpt

i'm beginner to Qt,

I wanted to know how can i interact with Printer like devices which are connected to LPT/Parallel port.
i just want to send the control codes to dot matrix printer and also receive the data from a device which is connected to Parallel port

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which platform do you target?

Comment: I'm trying for windows platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Qt API for accessing the parallel port so you will have to use the native platform API for that.

Comment: Yes I know, but is anything possible using QIODevice?